# java.lang.ClassCastException: weblogic.xml.jaxp.RegistrySAXTransformerFactory cannot be cast to javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory

Tags: xml, jakarta-ee, weblogic

I am trying to deploy the war in weblogic server and I am getting the the following error.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: weblogic.xml.jaxp.RegistrySAXTransformerFactory cannot be cast to javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory
```

My weblogic.xml is

```
<weblogic-web-app>
   <container-descriptor>
      <prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes>
   </container-descriptor>
</weblogic-web-app>
```

I am trying to deploy the web application which is successfully deployed in tomcat but not in weblogic server.I have included weblogic.xml in my web application and trying to deploy in weblogic server but getting the above exception.

Comment: do you have a xerces lib in your web app ? It should conflict with weblogic's

Comment: we didnot include that jar in pom.But it is automatically getting in in the lib folder.How to remove that jar?

Answer (score 0):

Make a search for maven's tightened libraries, most likely TransformerFactory will meet twice, WebLogic apparently casts the class in the wrong place, check the class tree and check who pulled up the second class and whether it is needed
[duplicate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4wBr.png), [dependency:tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkmYD.png). The solution is to check this lib and either remove it altogether, or remove part of it.